# Update a database column dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql> describe break;
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| start       | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end         | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| duration    | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date        | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| employee_id | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to calculate (and update) the 'duration' column using the start and end values from the above table. For example:

```
UPDATE break SET duration=TIMEDIFF(start, end) WHERE employee_id=1;
```

Alas, this sets the duration column to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

```
mysql> select * from break\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     id: 30
  start: 2013-08-06 15:43:17
    end: 2013-08-06 15:55:42
duration: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
   date: 2013-08-06 15:43:17
employee_id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

help

Comment: Why would you store the same information twice?  i.e. You have the start and end already, why need to store the difference?  Also your `duration` column shouldn't be a datetime, because it's a duration not an instant of time. I would probably use an `int` and store the number of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) (emphasis mine):

> TIMEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as **a time value**.

Change `duration` to type `TIME` and it should work.

Note that you are creating redundancy in your schema. This is usually a Bad Thing. What if `end` or `start` change and you do not update `duration`? Better use a view and return the `TIMEDIFF` calculated from `end` and `start` from there.

Answer (score 2):

Change `durration` to type `TIME` and then update your code

```
UPDATE break SET duration=TIMEDIFF(end, start) WHERE employee_id=1;
```

or you will be getting a negative durration

UPDATE: in response to another answer you can make a trigger that sets the duration every time the row is updated

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `break_trigger`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `break_trigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `break`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET duration=TIMEDIFF(end, start) WHERE employee_id= NEW.employee_id;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: My intentions were to have some kind of cumulative function going on in the table. Say, summing 2, 3 or n breaks for any particular given user on any day given.